Firebase wrong redirecting http://www -> https://www - > https://non-www
I have a webpage hosted on Firebase. The domain is intended to use non-WWW url. When checking SEO with an analyzer, it reports "Important: multiple redirects detected." I decided to verify this using wget.
Here is the wget output:
wget http://www.topdelotop.es | grep Location:
URL transformed to HTTPS due to an HSTS policy
--2024-06-03 17:44:17--  https://www.topdelotop.es/
Resolving www.topdelotop.es (www.topdelotop.es)... 199.36.158.100
Connecting to www.topdelotop.es (www.topdelotop.es)|199.36.158.100|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 301 Moved Permanently
Location: https://topdelotop.es/ [following]
--2024-06-03 17:44:17--  https://topdelotop.es/
Resolving topdelotop.es (topdelotop.es)... 199.36.158.100
Connecting to topdelotop.es (topdelotop.es)|199.36.158.100|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 244772 (239K) [text/html]

It seems like the redirection is "http://www" -> "https://". However, SEO analyzers (I have tried multiple) still show multiple redirects. Here are the screenshots from the analyzers:


I have tried:
{ 
  *Another options...,

  "hosting": {
    "redirects": [
      {
        "source": "http://www.topdelotop.es/**",
        "type": 301,
        "destination": "https://topdelotop.es/:splat"
      },
      {
        "source": "https://www.topdelotop.es/**",
        "type": 301,
        "destination": "https://topdelotop.es/:splat"
      }
    ]
  }
}

But it returns the same. (I have used another redirect checkers, just in case).
Can someone help me understand what might be wrong with my redirects?

If you throw http://www.stackoverflow.com into the WhereGoes tool, even StackOverflow has the same behaviour as what you have shown here. Which makes me think this is a non-issue. Just make sure that all your "Share URL" buttons and links use the canonical domain. The SEO analyzer is flagging the issue in case you are the cause of the multiple redirects (e.g. example.com/p/123456 to example.com/posts/123456 to example.com/posts/123456/how-to-make-pizza).

I see, probably not an issue. Thanks
